# Why can’t UIImagePickerController be pushed into navigation stack?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

When using `pushViewController` to push `UIImagePickerController`:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
```

an error will occur such as:

> Pushing a navigation controller is not supported

The right solution is to use `presentModalViewController`:

```
[self presentModalViewController:pvc animated:YES];
```

Can someone explain why this is necessary? What‘s hidden in `UIViewController`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apple does not allow stacking of navigation bars. Since the image picker has its own navigation bar, it cannot be placed in a navigation stack. The result would cause user confusion since there would be two bars, two sets of navigation items, two titles, etc.

Comment: but it is possible to hide one of the bars, using the `navigationBarHidden` property

Comment: Exactly, what if we want to use the UIImagePickerViewController with [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];