# I want to use UIPickerImageController inside UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to ask that how do I push UIPickerImageController if my app contains UINavigationController, please help me out

cz UIPickerImageController has a Navigation so what should I do, so what is apple way to solve this type of problem?

you can ask again if not clear about my question,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From UIImagePickerController [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

Present the user interface by calling the presentModalViewController:animated: method of the currently active view controller, passing your configured image picker controller as the new view controller. On iPad, you can alternatively present the user interface using a popover as described in initWithContentViewController: and “Presenting and Dismissing the Popover” in UIPopoverController Class Reference.

**UPDATE**

From [Why UIImagePickerController can not be push into navigation stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766514/why-uiimagepickercontroller-can-not-be-push-into-navigation-stack)

Apple does not allow stacking of navigation bars. Since the image picker has its own navigation bar, it cannot be placed in a navigation stack. The result would cause user confusion since there would be two bars, two sets of navigation items, two titles, etc.

Comment: this method doest not work, cz we push in navigationcontroller, not presentmodelviewcontroller, try on ur iphone and tell me what is happending

Comment: See if this helps you http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2498658&tstart=0&messageID=11870093