# Is it possible to integrate camera into navigation controller?

Tags: ios, camera

I want to use the camera in one of my future projects. Now I'm wondering if it is possible to have the camera on a normal view embedded into the navigation controller. Or is it always modal?

If it is possible how would you implement that?

Comment: You should maybe look into using AVFoundation, and roll your own camera.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can push a `UIImagePickerController`, since [Apple does not allow stacking of navigation bars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4829063)!

Perhaps you could add it to a subview like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.imagePickerController.view];
```